# Module resolver not working in react native web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I have existing project in that I have successfully added react-native-web package. in that project it was using module resolve path in all file with

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

and based on that babel.config.js and tsconfig.json: file.
But when I run for the web it giving error for module not found.

```
Example :
import { Example } from "~app/style/Example"
```

this is working in iOS but when I run in the web it not working. Please help.

Comment: Could you give some more information?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I simply add the alias in webpack and it works